# Can I create an Eclipse Product without an RCP Application?

Tags: eclipse, product

We develop plug-ins and a feature, and want to deliver a running application to our customer (so they don't have to get Eclipse on their own).  Basically, I want to put my plug-ins in a minimal Eclipse instance (minus jdt, junit, and other plug-ins that we don't need).

I created a product configuration, but it wants me to specify a **Product** and **Application** in the **Product Definition** definition section (of the Product Configuration editor).  How to I know what to specify for these?  Choosing willy-nilly gives me the following error when I click the *Launch an Eclipse application* from the Product Configuration editor:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
```

I've created products successfully from an RCP application before, but in this case I just want to deliver the bulk of Eclipse with our plug-ins installed.  Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

**Application** could be headless or have GUI like RCP.

**Product** is an abstract definition for your product, it must depend on a specific application to be executed. You could refer to the built-in applications of eclipse itself.

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to determine what built-in application might be appropriate for what I'm trying to do.